# Is it possible to create batches of transactions without using smart contracts?

Tags: transactions, synchronization, external-api

**Scenario:** Suppose that I have to make three transactions simultaneously to Alice, Bob and Claudia. Now the condition is if any one transaction fails the other two must also not go through.

**Query:** Is there any way to achieve this without using smart contracts? Is there any in-built feature of Ethereum Blockchain that can create batches for multiple transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike cryptocurrencies like Bitcoin, the Ethereum transaction format only allows for exactly 1 destination address. There is no way to achieve this without using a smart contract. I'm not sure why you want to avoid using a smart contract.

Something you can try is a smart contract that, when deployed, immediately performs the transfers and then destroys itself. For example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Multisend
{
    constructor(address[] memory destinations, uint256[] amounts) public payable
    {
        require(destinations.length == amounts.length);
        for (uint256 i=0; i<destinations.length; i++)
        {
            destinations[i].transfer(amounts[i]);
        }
        selfdestruct(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

Here you can see it in action:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xa03a304f1ef68f56874c1683d9f1e4bccb59fcb1634998fb861a16496f03abd3

Comment: Thanks! I was just curious to know if Ethereum Blockchain is all about smart contracts or I'm missing something. ;)